# cakePHP3.4.5のプロジェクトルートにあるhtaccessについて

Tags: cakephp

## 現象

composerを使ってさくらVPSにcakePHPを導入しました。
ただ、どうやっても表示されません。
InternalServerErrorになります。

## エラーログ

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.pr 

uri = /webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/webroot/
```

どうやら、.htaccessで無限ループを引き起こしてるっぽいのですが、よくわからないのです。

/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^$      webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (*)     webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

/webroot/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

ここに`[RewriteBase /]`をつけても状態は変わりませんでした。

/.htaccessの最後の

```
RewriteRule (*)     webroot/$1 [L]
```

をコメントにすると、最初の画面は表示されます。

ただ、ルーティングの設定が反映されないようです。

同じような現象を解決された方、もしくはお分かりになる方、お力添えいただけると幸いです。

Comment: apacheのドキュメントルートとアプリケーションの設置パスはどうなっていますか？要件として問題なければ、ドキュメントルートは、アプリケーションの `/webroot` に設定すべきです。

Comment: > nekketsuuさん
ご回答ありがとうございました。

すみません、書いておくべきでしたね。
ドキュメントルートは、/webrootになっております。

いろいろ試したのですが、全く解決しませんでした。
結局、Versionを3.3.6に落とすことで解決しました・・・。

Answer (score 1):

ひとまず、Versionを3.3.6に落とすことで解決しました。

-- 質問者さんのコメントより。

Answer (score 0):

intlモジュールがインストールされていないという可能性もあります。